# WARNING: Resolved nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space]

Tags: java, oracle, out-of-memory, clob

I am trying to retrieve a CLOB from Oracle SQL table. Clob is of around 25MB. I am getting an error :

> WARNING: Resolved [org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space]

Is there any way to retrieve the file?

Any other alternative approaches using Springboot.

This is the code:

```
public byte[] getData(String task) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("select OUTPUT_file from tablea where task = ?");
    
    byte[] fileBytes = jdbcTemplate.query(sb.toString(), new Object[]{task}, (rs) ->{
        if(rs.next()){
        
            byte[] resByteArry =new byte[0];
        Clob clob = rs.getClob("OUTPUT_file");
        resByteArry =getByteArrayByStream(clob.getAsciiStream());
        return resByteArry;
        }else {
            return new byte[0];
        }
        
    });
    
    return fileBytes;
}

private byte[] getByteArrayByStream(InputStream ins) {

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length =0;
    while( (length = ins.read(buffer,0,buffer.length)) !=-1){
        
        out.write(buffer,0,length);
        
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return out.toByteArray();

}
```

Comment: The “LOB” stands for ‘large object.’  They are not supposed to be held in program memory all at once.  That’s why CLOB has methods that return Reader or InputStream.  (You really should prefer Reader over InputStream to avoid charset conversion issues.)  Either change your method so it returns a Reader instead of `byte[]`, or pass an object which can process a Reader.  Both approaches allow you to read the CLOB without keeping it all in memory at once.

Comment: @VGR, thank you. Do you suggest any example where I can use Reader

Comment: You can learn how Reader works by reading [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Reader.html).  Exactly how you should use it will depend on what your application is doing with the CLOB data.